# Is second one passive form of the first one?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, tense, passive-voice, conjunctions

I am to deliver the money .

The money is to be delivered .

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is active voice and the second is passive voice.

Active voice, The subject is doing the activity.

**I** am to **deliver** the money.
In this example I (Subject) am to deliver (verb) the money. The subject is performing the action stated in the sentence.

Passive Voice, the subject is being acted upon.
I will rewrite the second sentence to illustrate better.

The **money** **is to be delivered** by me.
In this example money (Subject) is to be delivered (verb) by me. The subject is being acted upon by another noun. The money is not delivering itself.